# HTML5 Background Video not centering on mobile

Tags: css, html, video

im planing my Website and i want to have a fullscreen video background loop.

I wanted to implement something like those two:

http://theme.stepofweb.com/Smarty/v1.2.1/HTML/index-fullscreen-local-video.html
http://theme.stepofweb.com/Smarty/v1.2.1/HTML/index-fullscreen-youtube.html

As you can see when you resize your Browser Window to a mobile Screensize,
the Youtube-Variant centers the Video in the mobile-sized window.
But the local Video variant does not, it just keeps the very left part on-screen.

I want to use something like the local variant because it loads much quicker but would like to edit the css files, to center the video.
Is there any chance?

Is there any way you guys could help me, how i could center the video in the local variant?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please step first to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

### Full screen HTML5 video background.....

```css
video#videobg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background: url('images/poster.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 1s opacity;
}


/* ----------------------------------------------------
 GOOGLE FONTS
-------------------------------------------------------
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-family: "PT Sans",sans-serif;
font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
------------------------------------------------------- */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700|Raleway:400,300,700);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);

/* ----------------------------------------------------
 FONTS AWESOME
-------------------------------------------------------*/

@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.2.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.2.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.fa-arrow-left:before {
  content: "\f060";
}

.fa-edit:before,
.fa-pencil-square-o:before {
  content: "\f044";
}


/* ----------------------------------------------------
 STYLING
-------------------------------------------------------*/

.container>header,
.codeconvey-top {
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container>header {
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 95%;
}

.container>header h1 {
  font-size: 2.625em;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #f0f21e;
}

.container>header span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 60%;
  color: #ceccc6;
  padding: 0 0 0.6em 0.1em;
}


/* To Navigation Style */

.codeconvey-top {
  font-size: 0.69em;
  line-height: 2.2;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
}

.codeconvey-top a {
  color: #f0f21e;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: .6s background;
}

.codeconvey-top a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
  color: #716d62;
}

.codeconvey-top span.right {
  float: right;
}

.codeconvey-top span.right a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.container>section {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10em 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

.color-1 {
  background: #435a6b;
}

.color-2 {
  background: #f39c12;
}

.color-3 {
  background: #2ac56c;
}

.color-4 {
  background: #0e83cd;
}

.color-5 {
  background: #cd4436;
}

.color-6 {
  background: #f19f0f;
}

.color-7 {
  background: #3fa46a;
}

.color-8 {
  background: #ecf0f1;
}

.color-9 {
  background: #9e487f;
}

.color-10 {
  background: #16a085;
}

.color-11 {
  background: #aab7b7;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 25em) {
  .codeconvey-icon span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <!-- Top Navigation -->
  <div class="codeconvey-top clearfix">
    
   
  </div>
  <header>
    

  <video autoplay poster="images/poster.jpg" id="videobg" loop>
   <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B0JMGMGgxp9WMEdWb1hyQUhlOWs" type='video/mp4'/>
         
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Momin but this preview has the same problem that i mentioned.
When i watch the fullscreen preview and resize my browser to mobile device sizes, it just cuts off the right part and keeps the left part of the video, i would like a setting that the video centers and gets cut off on both sides equal, not the right part.
Any idea how to do that?